# PostgreSQL R package: encoded polish letters

Tags: r, postgresql, encoding

When I read table from Postgre SQL database I get encoded polish letters. The database has encoding **UTF8** and collation **Polish_Poland.1250**.

Code:

```
library(PostgreSQL)
# make connection
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host="localhost", port=xxxx, user="user", dbname="myBase")
# read tables and assign to variables
table <- dbReadTable(con, c("public","table"))
```

Results:

```
"BYDGOSZCZ"    "wĹ‚ocĹ‚awski" "WROCĹAW"  
"gostyĹ„ski"   "nowotarski"   "MOGILEĹSKI"  "myĹ›liborski"
```

Should be:

```
"BYDGOSZCZ"    "włocławski" "WROCŁAW"  
"gostyński"   "nowotarski"   "MOGILEŃSKI"  "myśliborski"
```

**I found the solution!!! This line should be added after the connection:**

`postgresqlpqExec(con, "SET client_encoding = 'windows-1250'")`.

Comment: lmgtfy, looks like you need to set your character set/multybyte encoding,  [link]( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/multibyte.html), either statically or on the fly.

Comment: Thank You @Chris but the problem was a little different. I placed the solution above.

Comment: İ think you can accept your own answer as solution though perhaps note that you are using Windows for future readers. Congrats!

Comment: Yes, exactly. The solution is for Windows users :)